# Ignite CacheStore implementation throwing ClassNotFoundException at server side

Tags: java, ignite, spring-cache

I am implementing CacheStore to write data asyn in database.
Code is working fine while running Ignite inside application as "Server" and data is getting saved in database.

Problematic scenerio :
Running remote node as server and application as "client",
While starting client node already started server nodes throws ClassNotFoundException.

Following are my configurations:

Server

```
<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="metricsLogFrequency" value="0"/>
    <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="marshaller">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller">
            <!-- Set to false to allow non-serializable objects in examples, default is true. -->
            <property name="requireSerializable" value="false"/>
        </bean>
        </property>

    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.zk.TcpDiscoveryZookeeperIpFinder">
                <property name="zkConnectionString" value="localhost:2181"/>
            </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Client :

```
CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration();
cacheConfiguration.setName(name);
cacheConfiguration.setBackups(backup);
cacheConfiguration.setRebalanceMode(CacheRebalanceMode.SYNC);
cacheConfiguration.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
LruEvictionPolicy evictionPolicy = new LruEvictionPolicy();
evictionPolicy.setMaxSize(maxEntries);
cacheConfiguration.setEvictionPolicy(evictionPolicy);
cacheConfiguration.setEvictSynchronized(true);
cacheConfiguration.setExpiryPolicyFactory(CreatedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(duration));
cacheConfiguration.setStartSize(100*1024*1024);
cacheConfiguration.setReadThrough(true);
cacheConfiguration.setWriteThrough(true);
cacheConfiguration.setWriteBehindEnabled(true);
cacheConfiguration.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
cacheConfiguration.setCacheStoreFactory(new FactoryBuilder.SingletonFactory<CacheStore>(cacheStore));



IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration = new IgniteConfiguration();
igniteConfiguration.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
TcpDiscoverySpi tcpDiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
TcpDiscoveryZookeeperIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryZookeeperIpFinder();
ipFinder.setZkConnectionString(zookeeperConString);
tcpDiscoverySpi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);

OptimizedMarshaller marshaller = new OptimizedMarshaller();
marshaller.setRequireSerializable(false);

igniteConfiguration.
                setCacheConfiguration(cacheConfiguration).
                setClientMode(isClient);
igniteConfiguration.setDiscoverySpi(tcpDiscoverySpi);
igniteConfiguration.setMarshaller(marshaller).
                setGridName(gridName).
                setMetricsLogFrequency(0);
SpringCacheManager springCacheManager = new SpringCacheManager();
springCacheManager.setConfiguration(igniteConfiguration);
```

Now, I dont want to deploy CacheStore on server node so I have enabled peerclassloading. But same exception was thrown so I check on internet and changed its atomicitymode to Transaction so CacheStore at Client will be used everytime.
But still facing same issue.

Comment: In your code I see that you are using OptimizedMarshaller, but there also exists BinaryMarshaller and with BinaryMarshaller - it does not require types on server nodes.

Answer (score 1):

All classes which present in CacheConfiguration should be available on all nodes. P2P classloading doesn't work for CacheStore. You need to deploy classes manually.

Comment: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/CacheStore-being-serialized-to-client-td1931.html

Comment: so should i make two different build one for updating cache ie client build and other is for updating database ie server build and then deploy these in different tomcat server. Or placing my jars in ignite's lib directory will work?

Comment: You need put your jars in \libs folder.